Movie where an artifact attaches itself to a man and turn him into a monster
What's the name of the movie where a young man finds this item that attaches itself to him and somehow turns him into a monster? I think it is from the '80's or '90's.
Other people are looking for that same item and they can turn into monsters as well. The movie goes on and the young man eventually kills the other guys in their monster form. The last bad guy transforms into the biggest monster of them all, but he is also ultimately killed by the young man in monster form. 
There was one part where they thought they had killed him but he emerged from another monster's belly by cutting his belly with a blade on his elbow. 
Was it called Magiver?

Was it animated or live action?  Was it in english?

You might be looking for an anime called The Guyver: Bio-Booster Armor, or the live action movie based off of it called The Guyver.
Live action movie description:

The Guyver (released in Europe as Mutronics) is a 1991 American science fiction film loosely based on the Japanese manga series of the
  same name. The film tells of a young man, Sean Barker, who discovers
  an alien artifact called The Unit which changes Barker into a
  alien-hybrid super soldier called The Guyver. Barker learns that a
  major corporation called Kronos is after The Guyver Unit and soon
  discovers that the people behind Kronos are not human after all. The
  film was met with a mixed to negative reaction from critics and fans.
  A sequel was followed in 1994 called Guyver: Dark Hero, which was
  received more favorably than its predecessor.

Or one of the many adaptations.

Yes thats it, Guyver. thats the movie i was talking about. i ask hundreds of people and they had no idea what i was talking about. the live action movie was what i watched and now i think am gonna look up the anime. thanks a million...

@aldane don't forget that you can select my answer as the accepted answer.  thank you.
